# How to extract accesss token value from one API response body(in one class) into another API header(in another class) in rest assured code

Tags: java, json, cucumber, authorization, rest-assured

Have one token generation API in one class which gives the below response.

```
{
    "access_token": "eyJraWQiOiJNR2FOQUtYXC9pa0grNE1wTE9aS05wMGtqbXNOd0lzXC9WXC9EYm1LZ0pZdTZNPSIsImFsZyI6IlJTMjU2In0.eyJzdWIiOiIxYjBtcjc4cHNjMHIyM25nYnJqMml1MnNkNCIsInRva2VuX3VzZSI6ImFjY2VzcyIsInNjb3BlIjoic2dwZi5wcm9kdWN0XC",
 "expires_in": 3600,
    "token_type": "Bearer"
}
```

Then have another Get API in another class in which I want to extract this access_token value in the header in rest assured code. So how can I take that access token value in another class?

```
public class Get_Service_List {
    
    private Response response;
    String BaseUrl = "https://dev.api.sgf.eus.nt/pro";
    
    
    
    
    
    @Given("Get Service list API")
    public void get_Service_list_API() {
     
        RestAssured.baseURI = BaseUrl;
        
    }

    @When("call the API with valid token and details")
    public void call_the_API_with_valid_token_and_details() {

        response = RestAssured.given()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .header("Authorization", "Bearer "+TokenGeneration.accessToken)
                .when()
                .get("/api/protsvc/ser");
    
    }

    @Then("validate the resonse body with list of services")
    public void validate_the_resonse_body_with_list_of_services() {
       
        String response_body = response.getBody().asString();
        System.out.println("response is: " +response_body);
    }

    @Then("validate for 200 status code")
    public void validate_for_status_code() {
      
        int status_code = response.getStatusCode();
        System.out.println("status is: " +status_code);
    
    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know much about how cucumber share state. Below is the way to extract `access_token` from response.

```
String accessToken = response.jsonPath().getString("access_token");
```